# Yesod Subsite Function Handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have an exposed function (a simple function with one Text argument, that performs IO operations and then returns a bool) in my subsite. But every time i call it from my main site `boolVal <- Sub.getVal "abc"` it throws the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Sub’ with ‘App’
Expected type: HandlerT App IO Bool 
Actual type: HandlerT Sub (HandlerT master0 IO) Bool
```

subsite code snippet

```
type SubHandler a = forall master. Yesod master => HandlerT Sub (HandlerT 
master IO) a

getVal :: Text -> SubHandler Bool
getVal name = do
    -- some operations including IO
    return False
```

main site code snippet

```
import Sub

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    boolVal <- Sub.getVal "abc"
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "home/index")
```

The subsite routes are working fine and i foolishly presumed the SubHandler would have registered with the main App, magically, like most things in haskell ha

thank you

FYI i would really appreciate a technical answer to this, and not just "the types don't match", albeit my understanding of classes and instances declarations is not all that great atm - work in progress :)

Comment: i have changed the type signature to: `getVal :: (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ master) => Text -> m Bool` and it works, however, the session data is returning `Nothing` :(

Comment: this signature also works: `getVal :: Yesod master => Text -> (HandlerT master IO) Bool`. But still the `lookupSession` value returns `Nothing`

Comment: have you tried `liftSubHandler`? since a sub site is an extra layer to a regular handler. https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.12/yesod-core-1.6.5/Yesod-Core.html#v:liftSubHandler

Comment: hmmm... im using `yesod >=1.4.3 && <1.5` and `yesod-core >=1.4.30 && <1.5` and `liftSubHandler` is not in scope @sbditto85

Comment: Problem Closed. I worked around the problem with an alternative solution.